# jQuery change picture of store item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a website with a store interface and I have multiple store items with 2 small pictures and a big picture. I want to be able to mouseover the smaller picture and change the source of the big picture to the same source as the currently moused over small picture.

```
<div id='store_checkout_image_div'>
    <img default-image='Images/test-shirt.jpg' src='Images/test-shirt.jpg' alt='Shirt' class='store_checkout_image'/>
    <div id='small_images'>
        <img id='store_image_1' src='Images/placeholder1.jpg' alt='Front' class='fade_store'/>
        <img id='store_image_2' src='Images/test-shirt.jpg' alt='Back' class='fade_store'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried my hand it making it work, and it does, but if multiple store items are there when I go to the next store item the picture is the same as the picture I previously used. Here is the jquery I have written. I am using php to grab item information and image source to create new store items in case that is important.

```
$('.fade_store').mouseover(function(){
    var currentPic = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.fade_store').fadeTo(0.15);
    $('.store_checkout_image').attr('src', currentPic);
});//end mouseover
```

Note, I would like to only change the the picture of the currently selected set of html divs. Currently If I have more than 1 set, the source of all divs with the class store_checkout_image will change.

Comment: Have you tired removing the attribute src before setting it again?

Comment: Looks okay to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Hz7x2/

Comment: @SimonAdcock Yes, I stated in the topic that it works. However when you add another set of the html tags you will see that it changes both .store_checkout_image sources

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe ?

```
$('.fade_store').mouseover(function(){
    var currentPic = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).parent().find('.fade_store:first').fadeTo(0.15);    
    $(this).parent().find('.store_checkout_image:first').attr('src', currentPic);
});//end mouseover
```

Comment: it would have to be .parent().parent() for it to actually change the image, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem of changing every .store_checkout_image. Thanks though!

Comment: yup indeed parent().parent()... my thought was that you were changing all images with the same class instead of one..

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should clear that up in the main topic!

Comment: Sorry, it actually works out but there seems to be some sort of problem with the way I am implementing the divs. I am using a plugin called Nyromodal that allows each div to pop up when a store item is clicked on. I tested out your code in a small test webpage and it actually worked out, there must be some weird problem with using this and nyromodal simultaneously.

Comment: It would work in a normal situation, unfortunately I found that my problem persists due to a weird interaction between my jquery and another jquery plugin called Nyromodal. I will have to continue looking into the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the first `store_checkout_image` element:

```
$('.fade_store').mouseover(function(){
    var currentPic = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.fade_store').fadeTo('slow', 0.15); 
    $('.store_checkout_image').eq(0).attr('src', currentPic);
});//end mouseover
```

Otherwise update `eq(0)` to point to the index of whichever element you need (`0` points to the first element, `1` to the second, etc).

Also, the `fadeTo` call isn't working correctly, try adding a transition speed:

```
$('.fade_store').fadeTo('slow', 0.15);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hz7x2/4/